# 'PQconnectdbParams' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, sql, c, postgresql

I am trying to debug a code written by someone. When I try to compile the file I get the following error.
**Error: 'PQconnectdbparams' was not declared in this scope.**
Below is the code snippet

```
int BSM::ConnectToDB()
{
int nRetVal = FS_SUCCESS;


if (m_pDBconn == NULL)
    m_pDBconn = PQconnectdbParams(m_pConnectionKeywords, (const char**)m_pConnectionValues, 0);

int nAttempt = 0;

do
{
    if(PQstatus(m_pDBconn) == CONNECTION_OK) break;

    PQreset(m_pDBconn);
} while(++nAttempt < nMaxAttemps);

if(PQstatus(m_pDBconn) != CONNECTION_OK)
{
    DisconnectFromDB();
    nRetVal = CONNECTION_ERROR;
}

return nRetVal;
}
```

Beginner in C++ and PostgreSQL. Any help appreciated

Comment: You haven't `#include` the correct header file(s), and/or you misspelled the function name.

Comment: Try adding `#include <libpq-fe.h>`.

Comment: The function name and the header files are included but still getting this issue.

Comment: This issue has been resolved. Basically the function 'PQconnectdbparams' was introduced from version 9.0 onwards. I had version 8.4.4 running. On upgrading, the issue was resolved. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been resolved. Basically the function 'PQconnectdbparams' was introduced from version 9.0 onwards. I had version 8.4.4 running. On upgrading, the issue was resolved. Thanks